# Counterexample for a solution of a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Construct an example of a differential equation depending on a parameter
$a$ for which some solutions do not depend continuously on $a$.

i was reading differential equations, dynamical systems and  introduction to chaos - Hirsch book and, in the chapter 7, i did not find any counterexample, please can anyone help me whit this? i was thinking this for 3 days, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $y'+a^xy=0$. What happens if $a=1$? And if $a \in (0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$?

Comment: ok, i get it, the solution when $a=1$ is $y(t)=ce^{-x}$, and the solution when $a \neq 1$ is $y(t)=ce^{a^t/lna}$ and that solution is not continous if $a \leq 0$ is correct? but, then, we need to take $a \in (-\infty, \infty)$ or not?

Comment: When $a=1$ we have that $\ln a=0$, and $\ln a$ shows up in the denominator of the exponent of the solution to the case $a\neq 1$.